# Deserializing XML Response using RestSharp

Tags: c#, xml, api, restsharp

I have read through the various questions already posed here regarding this subject and i'm still no closer to solving my problem.

I am trying to Deserialize this xml response:

```
 <?xml version="1.0" encoding="ISO-8859-1" ?>
   <SubmissionResult>
     <Result>ACCEPTED</Result>
       <SubmissionID>
         <RefNo>77587-1425386500</RefNo>
         <Submitted>9</Submitted>
         <ValidNo>7</ValidNo>
         <InvalidNo>2</InvalidNo>
         <InvalidNo_1>08452782055</InvalidNo_1>
         <InvalidNo_2>01234567890</InvalidNo_1>
         <TextvID>77587-1425386500</TextvID>
       </SubmissionID>
     <Credits>999999</Credits>
   </SubmissionResult>
```

Using these classes:

```
[XmlRoot ("SubmissionResult")]
public class SubmissionResult
{
    [XmlElement ("Result")]
    public string Result { get; set; }
    public SubmissionID SubmissionID { get; set; }
    [XmlElement("Credits")]
    public int Credits { get; set; }
}

public class SubmissionID
{
    [XmlElement("RefNo")]    
    public int RefNo { get; set; }
    [XmlElement("Submitted")]    
    public int Submitted { get; set; }
    [XmlElement("ValidNo")]    
    public int ValidNo { get; set; }
    [XmlElement("TextVID")]    
    public string TextVID { get; set; }
}
```

However I am only ever returning null and 0 values, which I assume are the default.

Here is the code to get the results and hopefully deserialize:

```
try
{
    var request = new RestRequest();
    request.RequestFormat = DataFormat.Xml;
    request.Resource = APIURL;
    request.RootElement = "SubmissionResult";

    SubmissionResult r = Execute<SubmissionResult>(request);
}

public static T Execute<T>(RestRequest request) where T : new()
{
     var client = new RestClient();
         client.BaseUrl = new  Uri("https://www.textvertising.co.uk/_admin/api", UriKind.Absolute);

     var response = client.Execute<T>(request);

     return response.Data;
}
```

Many thanks in advance for any help you can provide.

CS

Comment: TextvID has incompatible casing in the XML and code attribute. Minor and probably not relevant, but you should still fix that.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

I made a few changes and could make it work:

Probably a typo in the question but something I had to change is that posted XML is invalid:

```
<InvalidNo_2>01234567890</InvalidNo_1>
```

I understand you want use .NET XMLSerializer as you used XmlRoot and XmlElement annotations so you have to override the default one that comes with RestSharp like so:

```
request.XmlSerializer = new RestSharp.Serializers.DotNetXmlSerializer();
```

Also I had to delete the RootElement setting which didn't play nicely with .NET serializer so deleted the following line:

```
request.RootElement = "SubmissionResult";
```

So my version became:

```
var request = new RestRequest();
request.XmlSerializer = new RestSharp.Serializers.DotNetXmlSerializer();
request.RequestFormat = DataFormat.Xml;
// request.Resource = APIURL;

SubmissionResult r = Execute<SubmissionResult>(request);
```

Finally I noticed RefNo is meant to be integer in the class but the returned value is not (77587-1425386500) so I made it a string:

```
[XmlElement("RefNo")]
public string RefNo { get; set; }
```

I created a mock response at mocky.io at tested with that and it seems to be working fine:

```
public static T Execute<T>(RestRequest request) where T : new()
{
    var client = new RestClient();
    client.BaseUrl = new Uri("http://www.mocky.io/v2/56cd88660f00009800d61ff8", UriKind.Absolute);

    var response = client.Execute<T>(request);

    return response.Data;
}
```

Answer (score 4):

Simple code to De-serialize xml response

```
//Create object of RestClient
IRestClient restClient = new RestClient();

//Create request with return type of payload as xml and method as GET
IRestRequest restRequest = new RestRequest(Url);
restRequest.AddHeader("Accept", "application/xml");
restRequest.Method = Method.GET;

//Execute the request to fetch the response
IRestResponse restResponse = restClient.Execute(restRequest);

//This is wrapper for System.Xml.Serialization.XmlSerializer 
var dotNetXmlDeserializer = new RestSharp.Deserializers.DotNetXmlDeserializer();
ModelClassName modelClassObject =
 dotNetXmlDeserializer.Deserialize<ModelClassName>(restResponse);

 Console.WriteLine(ModelClassName.PropertyName);
```

Where ModelClassName is the POCO class we create to store the response in de-serialized form.

> You can paste the copied payload in JSON/XML format into POCO class by
> using Visual Studios in built feature. Edit -> Paste Special -> Paste
> JSON/XML as classes

Comment: "Edit -> Paste Special -> Paste JSON/XML as classes" Wow, I wished I knew about this a decade ago! Excellent tip :)

Answer (score -3):

Using Restsharp i normally do a different approach but i am mainly working with JSON. Is this using MVC web api?

I would create a Client being of Type `IRestClient` where i would set the API url and some headers. I would then use,

```
var response = client.Post<T>(DataFormat.Json, "admin/api", content); 
if(response.Data != null)
//populate T object with data
```

If you could please provide some more information on the web service method you are calling.. it would help thanks :) good luck with this..

Have a look at this
http://restsharp.org/
To be honest i have never used the `RestClient.Execute<>` myself but this link should hopefully help