# Read RestSharp response and save data to class

Tags: c#, xml, rest, restsharp

I send a RestRequest and receive the response in xml format.
This is my code:

```
class Employee 
{
    int id;
    string name;
}
```

```
private void reqEmployee(Employee empl)
{
    var client = new RestClient(ConfigurationManager.AppSettings["base_url"] + "/" +
                                ConfigurationManager.AppSettings["provider"] + "/" +
                                ConfigurationManager.AppSettings["serviceName"])
    {
        Timeout = -1
    };

    var request = new RestRequest(Method.POST);

    var authenticationString = string.Format("{0}:{1}", ConfigurationManager.AppSettings["serviceUser"], ConfigurationManager.AppSettings["servicePass"]);
    var base64EncodedAuthenticationString = Convert.ToBase64String(System.Text.ASCIIEncoding.ASCII.GetBytes(authenticationString));

    request.AddHeader("Authorization", "Basic " + base64EncodedAuthenticationString);
    request.AddHeader("Content-Type", "text/plain");

    var body = @"<GetEmployee xmlns=""http://test.dev.com/"">"
                + "\n" + @"    <Id>" + empl.idno + "</Id>"
                + "\n" + @"</GetEmployee>";


    request.AddParameter("text/plain", body, ParameterType.RequestBody);

    IRestResponse response = client.Execute(request);
}
```

Example of the request I send:

```xml
<GetEmployee xmlns="http://test.dev.com/">
    <Id>4132</Id>   
</GetEmployee>
```

Example of the response I receive (`response.Content`):

```xml
<GetEmployeeResponse xmlns="http://test.dev.com/">
    <PropertyStatus xmlns:i="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance">
        <Employee>
            <Name>John</Name>
            <Id>6584</Id>
        </Employee>
        <Employee>
            <Name>Chris</Name>
            <Id>4120</Id>
        </Employee>
    </PropertyStatus>
</GetEmployeeResponse>
```

How can I fill a `List<Employee>` with `response.Content`?

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Building XML request with RestSharp](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/34527935/building-xml-request-with-restsharp)

Comment: Thank you for the asnwer, this link is about sending a request with an array of objects, I just want to read the response and save it as an array of employee

Comment: If you set the DataFormat and Serializer on the request then you can call the `Execute<T>` where you can specify `List<Employee>` as the expected output.

Comment: Here is [another SO thread](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/35598796/deserializing-xml-response-using-restsharp) where this concept is detailed.

Answer (score 0):

You just need to:

- configure the default XML serializer
- prepare your POCO class to be serializable with serialization attributes
- use RestSharp Client generic `Execute<T>`

https://restsharp.dev/usage/serialization.html#default-serializers

https://restsharp.dev/getting-started/getting-started.html#content-type