# How do I read xml from an endpoint url and deserialize into a c# object in .net core?

Tags: .net, xml, serialization

How can I get data from a url in xml format and serialize into a C# object in .Net core?
I have tried a few option but they don t work using http client.
Any help pointing to the right way to do it as I see many ways and I am not sure which is the appropriate way for .net core

Comment: Show what you've tried and explain how it failed.

Comment: All tutorials uses json I need some example with xml

Comment: This can help you: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/35598796/deserializing-xml-response-using-restsharp

Comment: Please provide enough code so others can better understand or reproduce the problem.